# Why my setInterval runs only once?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I don't know where is the problem point... (T.T)

**script is**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printTime(arg) {
    var mydate = new Date();
    document.getElementById(arg).innerHTML = mydate;
}
function startTimer(arg) {
    setInterval(printTime(arg), 1000);
}
</script>
```

**HTML is**

```
<body onload="startTimer('timer')">
    <h1 id="timer">
    </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: You are calling the function, not referencing it   `setInterval(function() { printTime(arg); }, 1000);`

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only executing the function initially and setting the returned value as an argument instead use a callback function.

```html
<body onload="startTimer('timer')">
  <h1 id="timer">
    </h1>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function printTime(arg) {
    var mydate = new Date();
    document.getElementById(arg).innerHTML = mydate;
  }

  function startTimer(arg) {
    setInterval(function() {
      printTime(arg)
    }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

---

Or bind the argument as `this` context using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method and within the function you can get value from `this`.

```html
<body onload="startTimer('timer')">
  <h1 id="timer">
    </h1>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function printTime() {
    var mydate = new Date();
    document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = mydate;
  }

  function startTimer(arg) {
    setInterval(printTime.bind(arg), 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and accurate answer.

Comment: Really thank you for explanation for bind. it's cool!